# Defining functions with a for loop

Tags: php, wordpress, for-loop

I have a section of code that looks as follows:

```
     function macro_ad_short_code_function(){
        return wp_get_attachment_image(get_option('macro_ad_image_uploader'));
    } 

     function pods_ad_short_code_function(){
        return wp_get_attachment_image(get_option('pods_ad_image_uploader'));
    } 

     function live_foods_ad_short_code_function(){
        return wp_get_attachment_image(get_option('live_foods_ad_image_uploader'));
    } 

     function captive_fish_ad_short_code_function(){
        return wp_get_attachment_image(get_option('captive_fish_ad_image_uploader'));
    } 

     function captive_inverts_ad_short_code_function(){
        return wp_get_attachment_image(get_option('captive_inverts_ad_image_uploader'));
    } 

     function refugium_ad_short_code_function(){
        return wp_get_attachment_image(get_option('refugium_ad_image_uploader'));
    } 

     function coral_ad_short_code_function(){
        return wp_get_attachment_image(get_option('coral_ad_image_uploader'));
    } 

     function cleanup_ad_short_code_function(){
        return wp_get_attachment_image(get_option('cleanup_ad_image_uploader'));
    } 

     function saltwater_ad_short_code_function(){
        return wp_get_attachment_image(get_option('saltwater_ad_image_uploader'));
    } 

     function shipping_ad_short_code_function(){
        return wp_get_attachment_image(get_option('shipping_ad_image_uploader'));
    } 

     function white_ad_short_code_function(){
        return wp_get_attachment_image(get_option('white_ad_image_uploader'));
    } 

     function wholesale_ad_short_code_function(){
        return wp_get_attachment_image(get_option('wholesale_ad_image_uploader'));
    } 




     function add_shorty() {



         add_shortcode(get_option('macro_ad_short_code'), 'macro_ad_short_code_function');
         add_shortcode(get_option('pods_ad_short_code'), 'pods_ad_short_code_function');
         add_shortcode(get_option('live_foods_ad_short_code'), 'live_foods_ad_short_code_function');
         add_shortcode(get_option('captive_fish_ad_short_code'), 'captive_fish_ad_short_code_function');
         add_shortcode(get_option('captive_inverts_ad_short_code'), 'captive_inverts_ad_short_code_function');
         add_shortcode(get_option('refugium_ad_short_code'), 'refugium_ad_short_code_function');
         add_shortcode(get_option('coral_ad_short_code'), 'coral_ad_short_code_function');
         add_shortcode(get_option('cleanup_ad_short_code'), 'cleanup_ad_short_code_function');
         add_shortcode(get_option('saltwater_ad_short_code'), 'saltwater_ad_short_code_function');
         add_shortcode(get_option('shipping_ad_short_code'), 'shipping_ad_short_code_function');
         add_shortcode(get_option('white_ad_short_code'), 'white_ad_short_code_function');
         add_shortcode(get_option('wholesale_ad_short_code'), 'wholesale_ad_short_code_function');


    }




    add_action('plugins_loaded', 'add_shorty');
```

Is there a cleaner way to write this with a for loop? (I understand how I would do this for the function **add_shorty**, but I am not sure how I would have a loop that would define the functions macro_ad_short_code_function, pods_ad_short_code_function, etc.

It looks like this(https://stackoverflow.com/a/2112337/5439315) might be a viable way, but that was 2 PHP versions ago

Answer (score 0):

So, you could use a [function alias](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.use) to just rename functions but that's not going to help with your `get_option` argument.  The solution you posted seems to be the best answer if the functions are not part of a class.  If you are in a class, use the magic __call() method and check if the function name matches `^(.+)_ad_short_code_function$` and then use the match in the `get_option` argument as so: `return wp_get_attachment_image(get_option("{$match}_ad_image_uploader"));`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [anonymous functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) to achieve this. I have not tested it but I think you can apply the concept:

```
function add_shorty()
{
    $shortcodes = ['macro_ad', 'pods_ad', 'live_foods_ad', 'captive_fish', 'refugium_ad', 'coral_ad', 'cleanup_ad', 'saltwater_ad', 'shipping_ad', 'white_ad', 'wholesale_ad'];
    foreach ($shortcodes as $s) {
        add_shortcode(get_option($s . '_short_code'), function () use ($s) {
            return wp_get_attachment_image(get_option($s . '_image_uploader'));
        });
    }
}

add_action('plugins_loaded', 'add_shorty');
```